# Can i upgradeWSO2 identity server version 5.1.0-beta to 5.3.0 directly?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity server version 5.1.0-beta. I want to upgrade to 5.3.0. How can i upgrade the version without loosing my data. Do i need to upgrade 5.1.0 then 5.2.0 then 5.3.0 ?

Expecting WSO2 identity server documentation to upgrade from 5.1.0 to 5.3.0 directly.

Anyone help me to find the document. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly migrate to 5.3.0 from 5.1.0. You need to first migrated to 5.2.0[1] then to 5.3.0[2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me with this also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842743/how-to-migrate-user-store-data-from-ldap-to-rdbms-in-wso2-identity-server

Comment: I am using 5.1.0-beta version. Can i upgrade to 5.2.0 directly?